# How to add multiple labels inside content Page Header

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to add multiple labels inside content Page Header.

I try with title and icon property of content page using which i can add image and tile to page.

I want to design page something like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8mgp.png)

Comment: https://github.com/ScienceSoft-Inc/TitleBar

Comment: thank you ..............